# How can I place a Photoshop document in Illustrator and preserve the layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers

I have not used Adobe Illustrator much, so please excuse me if this is obvious.

I'm trying to import a photoshop mockup of a logo into illustrator so I can finish it as a vector image. The problem is when I go to file.. place, and select the photoshop document, it doesn't preserve the layers. There will be a "layer 1" layer in the panel, and if I click the arrow next to it it will expand into one other layer, "filename.psd". This layer contains the bitmap of the entire flattened image, not individual layers as I would like to work with.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing your PSD file in Illustrator, open your PSD file in Illustrator. When the option box comes up:
[image: convert layers]

Change the option from "Flatten Layers to a Single Image" to "Convert Layers to Objects"
Your layers will now be retained in Illustrator.
Good luck!

changing layers opacity:

[image: layers]

Comment: I've already tried this, and it seems to have defaulted to whatever option I chose the first time. (although I think it is what you suggested, not sure though). Is there a way to bring back the dialog box that you show in the screenshot to test this? EDIT: Actually, it looks like it's taking *some* of the layers and separating them when I do it. Others (the important ones in this case) don't transfer with the "open" command. I figured out that dragging the file from windows explorer into illustrator brings back the dialog box, btw.

Comment: Try going to: Edit > Preferences > General and click "RESET ALL WARNING DIALOGS" (box at bottom) and then try opening your PSD in Illustrator again. What version of CS are you working in? My screenshot is from CS6.

Comment: This is CS5. Resetting the dialog boxes worked, but as before when I select "open" it will transfer some layers, but flatten others. Could it be because some of these have partial transparency and not others? I can post screenshots if necessary.

Comment: Try posting a screenshot, been awhile since I've been in CS5 will definitely do what I can to help!

Comment: The transparency might be an issue, can you make them all 100% (if that is an option) and then try the open function (at least then we can debug the issue regarding different transparency).

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to make them all 100% or 0% transparency, I'll keep working on it

Comment: I edited my response to you to include a screenshot of changing the layers opacity in photoshop

Comment: Yeah, the offending layers are all 100% layer opacity. I was meaning they had some partially transparent pixels in there, but that doesn't seem to be the case. When I create a new image with 4 layers in photoshop: layer 1 is a solid gradient, 2 is a solid gradient with the layer opacity decreased, 3 is half solid half transparent (0% or 100%, nothing in between) and layer 4 is a gradient fading from solid to transparent. All of them open in Illustrator perfectly EXCEPT 2, which didn't retain the layer opacity (but was separate from the rest). So it doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: Ok this seems to be a problem specific to your file, I would try to do one of two things then. Depending on the number of layers (4 or under) copy and paste them into their own files, open each up individually in Illustrator, merge them into a new file, or do the same in Photoshop, do a new PSD file and transfer each layer over to the new PSD, save and open. There might be something corrupt within your original PSD.

Comment: I will try that. For future reference, I'm uploading a couple screenshots now.

Comment: Here's two screenshots, first one is photoshop, second is illustrator after using the open command: http://imgur.com/a/MNWDu

Comment: And suddenly, a wild outage attacks! Anyway, copying all of the layers to a new PSD didn't work, I can try a few other things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14366/discussion-between-blue-dragon360-and-shannonmac)

Comment: Hm, it seems after clicking the "move discussion to chat" link I cannot chat because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Ok, I've tried copying each layer's bitmap over to a completely new file, and redoing all the layer settings (like the shadow opacity) from scratch. None of it works. That single file for some reason will not copy over to illustrator correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well... It turns out it was the layer mode/opacity after all! For some reason, it didn't realize that I had updated the file until Illustrator was restarted, so it was confusing me. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, I was about to loose money from my client